# with open(...) isn't closing my file when execution exits the block

Tags: python, temporary-files

I was wondering why I'm getting the error:

`[WinError32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`

When I write to the temporary file using `with`:

```
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

tmp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
tmp_file_name = tmp_file.name
with open(tmp_file_name, "w") as fp:
    print("Hello", file=fp)
Path(tmp_file_name).unlink()
```

Whereas if I manually close the file, everything is fine:

```
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

tmp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
tmp_file_name = tmp_file.name
tmp_file.write(b"Hello")
tmp_file.close()
Path(tmp_file_name).unlink()
```

Though this behavior only happens on Windows OS and not on OSX, or Linux.

In the [Tempfile docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) it states:

> Whether the name can be used to open the file a second time, while the named temporary file is still open, varies across platforms (it can be so used on Unix; it cannot on Windows NT or later).

Though my understanding is that when the execution leaves the `with` block, the file is automatically closed. So what is causing the file to be opened?

Comment: `NamedTemporaryFile` returns an open file handle; why are you trying to open it again? The documentation specifically says you cannot open an already opened file on Windows.

Comment: In your code you have `file=f`, but nowhere in the code do you define `f`. Are you certain that the exact code you posted behaves the way you say it does?

Comment: You're opening a file twice (`NamedTemporaryFile(...)` and `with ...`, but only closing it once (exiting the `with`).

Comment: Ahh, everything makes sense... It returns an open file handle my mistake, should have read the docs more clearly.

Comment: @BryanOakley sorry that was a typo I've fixed it